# Aggregation on mapping in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to apply aggregation in elastic on field count
Example:

domain:["config","test"] <----- field

I want to check that how many times this domain is present in docs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the domain field, but you need to make sure that `domain` field or its subfield is of the keyword type.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I want that how many times domain is present in doc not its values. For example there are 3 docs in with below details:
(1) "domain": ["test","conf"]
(2) "domain" : ["test","data"]
(3) "list" : { "sys":"hi"}

SO the answer should be like this
{"domain" : 2}
{"list": 1}

Comment: as per elastic guide, if I will apply with term then my result will be

"domain":{
         "test" <--- count 2
           "conf" <-- count 1
etc}

But I want my output like 
"domain" <--- count(2)

as it present two times in my document